# how to convert a string received from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following code in a parquet file, which I convert into a variable using collect:

```py
mapping_in_parquet = [('filial','filial','S','string'),('doc','numero_do_documento','S','string'),('serie','serie_do_documento','S','string')]

mapping = (df.select('mapping').distinct().collect()[0][0])
```

The problem is when I try to convert the string back to dataframe:

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("fieldName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("alias", StringType(), True),
    StructField("column_active", StringType(), True),
    StructField("typeField", StringType(), True)])

df = (spark.createDataFrame(mapping, schema))

print(mapping)
```

I get error:

```
StructType can not accept object '[' in type
```

When playing the code directly in the console I don't get any error. The error occurs when I extract the column value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code:

- First is typo while creating dataframe: Use `df = (spark.createDataFrame(mapping_in_parquet, schema))`.
- Second, in `mapping = (df.select('mapping').distinct().collect()[0][0])`, there is no column `mapping`. Use either of `[fieldName, alias, typeField, column_active]`.

Full example code with correction:

```py
mapping_in_parquet = [('filial','filial','S','string'),('doc','numero_do_documento','S','string'),('serie','serie_do_documento','S','string')]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("fieldName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("alias", StringType(), True),
    StructField("column_active", StringType(), True),
    StructField("typeField", StringType(), True)])

df = (spark.createDataFrame(mapping_in_parquet, schema))

mapping = (df.select('fieldName').distinct().collect()[0][0])

print(mapping)

[Out]:
doc
```

Comment: @SrKartcheski, does this solve your problem?